# HTTP_referer for multiple URL's

Tags: php, http-referer

I Got this "HTTP_referer-script" that checks if a visitor comes from a certain URL (password protected) when entering the site. My problem is that It only seems to work if the visitor comes from the absolute right URL. I.e:

If the user comes from: http://mydomain.com it works fine but if the user comes from http://www.mydomain.com it wont work.

Is there anyway to add a second URL to the HTTP_referer in this case the same domain but with "www" aswell?

```
<?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

if ($referrer != 'http://mydomain.com/') { 
    die("You do not have access to this site."); 
} 

// put your page code here 

?>
<h1>Content here</h1>
```

Thanks a lot!
/a

Comment: Why not adding the second URL in the conditional statement: `if($referrer != 'http://mydomain.com/' || $referrer != 'http://www.mydomain.com/')`

Comment: You might want to try the `||` operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Like this?
    if ($referrer != 'http://theportfolio.se/' || $referrer != 'http://www.theportfolio.se/') 
        die("You shall not pass!");

Comment: Don't seems to work it wont say either "You dont..." or "Content here" now... Hmm!

Comment: don't use a semicolon (;) before the ||. also both URLs are the same in your example, which makes no sense.
and keep in mind that your code is not a security check, since the visitor could fake his referrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` are derived from the request the client sends to your webserver. First of all it is important to realize that this information is by no means to be trusted. It is easily faked by the client.

That being said. What you probably want to do is simply check if the domain is part of the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` string. Because in this case https://domain.com also wouln`t work.

So by your example, use this:

```
<?php 

if ( strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'mydomain.com') ) { 
    die("You do not have access to this site."); 
} 

// put your page code here 

?>
<h1>Content here</h1>
```

This code simply checks if "mydomain.com" is part of the contents of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Do realize this would also mean: http://www.somedomain.com?test=mydomain.com as referer would also match, but it is not very likely you will run into that situation (nor will it probably matter..)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunaley it didn't work. Should the url be the full url like "http://www.mydomain.com/"? Can it have something to do with the password-page used ahead of this page?

Comment: Yeay! Got it to work! Thanks alot! I just by changing the URL from index.php to auth.php (the page the checks the password) and then everything worked like a charm... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array` in conjunction with array of urls:

```
if (!in_array($referrer, array('http://mydomain.com/', 'http://www.mydomain.com/'))) { 
    die("You do not have access to this site."); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put two if statements as follows.

```
 <?php 
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 

if ($referrer != 'http://mydomain.com/') { 
    die("You do not have access to this site."); 
} 
if ($referrer != 'http://www.mydomain.com/') { 
    die("You do not have access to this site."); 
} 


// put your page code here 

?>
<h1>Content here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowed = array("hello.com","example2.com");

foreach ($allowed as $site) {
    if(!preg_match("#$site#", $url))
         die("You do not have access to this site."); 
    else
        break;
}
```